# Modifying y-axis label in pdf Diagram

Tags: pdf, diagrams

I have mislabelled the y-axis in my pdf graph that I generated from an Matlab file.
Unfortuantely, I cant find anymore the data that I used to generate the graph. So I am wondering if there is an free tool that allows me to rename the y-axis in my pdf diagram?
Are there any free tools available that could be helpful or is this something "impossible"
to do?

Many thanks for your help,
Andrea

Comment: imho, the simplest solution would be to get a pdf editing program, get the picture /diagram/ out, edit it in some sort of photo manipulation program, and jam it back in afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

[Inkspace](http://inkscape.org/) is good, for this purpose. It is a free tool for editing vector graphics files, similar to Illustrator or CorelDraw.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively import the file into photoshop and edit it with the text tools (and eraser) and then print it back into a .pdf.